# What is the correct operation of a CANopen inhibit timer?

Tags: canopen

I understand that the operation of a CANopen inhibit timer is to ensure a minimum time between successive transmissions of the same message, but the specification does not make it clear what to do if the data changes during the inhibit time (and the transmission is on change-of-state). Should I buffer the data and transmit it when the inhibit timer expires, or discard it and wait for a change after the timer has expired?

My assumption would be, since it is *not* clearly defined, I can choose whichever approach I want, but I'd appreciate the input of any experienced architects / developers on this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that the inhibit time is simply the minimum time between consecutive CAN frames with the same CAN-ID. The standard does not specify the behavior for multiple events during the inhibit time window, because it depends on the situation.

For services like NMT, EMCY and perhaps LSS, you'd want to buffer the messages and send them later. In this case the inhibit time is simply a means to help slow (or badly programmed) devices to handle short bursts of messages. I've seen devices that could only handle 3 CAN frames at once, so it's often necessary, but you would not want them to miss messages.

For event-driven Transmit-PDOs, it depends on what the PDO represents. If you use it to track state, it might make sense to drop events during the inhibit window. They're invalidated by subsequent events anyway. To ensure you always emit the latest state, you can store the most recent event and transmit it once the inhibit time has elapsed, or use the event-timer to ensure you're never too far behind. I've used this strategy in the past for analog inputs where line noise would sometimes cause event bursts.

If you use PDOs to track events (or state changes), you'd be better of buffering them so no events get lost. However, this can introduce potentially unbounded delays if the event period is shorter than the inhibit time.

For the products we're working on at Lely (dairy farm robots), we actually prefer to use SYNC-driven PDOs instead. It results in a much more predictable CAN bus load. And we don't have to track state at the receiver side because we receive a full update on every SYNC. However, the receiver is always one SYNC period behind the transmitter, so this may not be appropriate for your use case.